# How to access the parent data eloquent join

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

i have two tables **products** and **orders** 
i am able to access all data in the table **Order** but can't access **products** product_name

**below is the Order model**

```
class Order extends Model
     {
    // Table name
     protected $tablename = 'orders';
    // primary key
     public $primaryKey = 'id';

     public function products(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
     }
 }
```

**Product** model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    // Table name
    protected $tablename = 'products';
    // primary key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    // Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;    

    public function orders(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
     }
}
```

in my controller i have this **OrderController**

```
class OrdersController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index(){
        $orderedProducts = Order::with('products')->paginate(5);
        return view::make('orders.index')->with('products',$orderedProducts);
    }
}
```

now trying to access the **product_name** on the view fails

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
  <tr>
 <td>{{'#'.++$i}}</td>
 <td>{{$product->product_name}}</td> //fails to get this from products table
 <td>{{$product->quantity}}</td>
 <td>{{$product->totalPrice}}</td>
 <td>{{$product->totalPrice * $product->quantity }}</td>
 <td>{{$product->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
 <td>{{$product->orderStatus}}</td>                                                                         
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally figured it by changing my **Order model** method from **products** to **product** because it was having the same name  with `protected $tablename = 'products';` in the **Product model** then after that i referenced the related method **product** in the **Order model** directly in the view as follow `<td>{{$product->product->product_name}}</td>`

the complete working code now below

**Order model** where i changed the method from **products** to **product**

```
class Order extends Model
{
    // Table name
    protected $tablename = 'orders';
    // primary key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';


    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

**Product model**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    // Table name
    protected $tablename = 'products';
    // primary key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    // Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;    

    public function orders(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
     }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index(){
        $order = Order::with('product')->paginate(5);
        return view::make('orders.index')->with('order',$order);
    }
```

lastly on the **view** where i make reference to the method **product** in the **Order model**

```
@foreach ($order as $product)
    @if (!empty($product))
     <tr>      
       <td>{{$product->product->product_name}}</td> **//Here is the referencing**
       <td>{{$product->quantity}}</td>
       <td>{{$product->totalPrice}}</td>
       <td>{{$product->totalPrice * $product->quantity }}</td>
       <td>{{$product->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
       <td>{{$product->orderStatus}}</td>                                                                         
     </tr>                                                   
   @endif                                                     
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to do so

Controller:

```
public function index(){
    $order = Order::with('products')->paginate(5);
    return view::make('orders.index')->with('products',$order->products);
}
```

or

Controller:

```
public function index(){
    $order = Order::with('products')->paginate(5);
    return view::make('orders.index')->with('order',$order);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($order->products as $product)
@if(!empty($product))
  <tr>
 <td>{{'#'.$loop->iteration}}</td>
 <td>{{$product->product_name}}</td> //fails to get this from products table
 <td>{{$product->quantity}}</td>
 <td>{{$product->totalPrice}}</td>
 <td>{{$product->totalPrice * $product->quantity }}</td>
 <td>{{$product->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
 <td>{{$product->orderStatus}}</td>                                                                         
 </tr>
@endif 
@endforeach
```

Comment: it throw error at ```@foreach ($order->products as $product)``` because of the products supplied to foreach, saying **Property [products] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\healmass\resources\views\orders\index.blade.php)**